# azure self hosted agent linux do not run with "--once" parameter

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

i like to run the self-hosted Linux container only once per pipeline
that means when the pipeline is done i like the container to stop
i saw that there is a parameter called "--once"
please this link in the bottom :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

but when i start the docker like this with the once after the run  :

```
docker run --once --rm -it -e AZP_WORK=/home/working_dir -v /home/working_dir:/azp -e AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/xxxx -e AZP_TOKEN=nhxxxxxu76mlua -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=ios_dockeragent xxx.xxx.com:2000/azure_self_hosted_agent/agent:latest
```

I'm getting :

```
unknown flag: --once
See 'docker run --help'.
```

also if i put it in the docker file
as

```
COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh --once"]
```

Im getting error when trying to run the docker :

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./start.sh --once\": stat ./start.sh --once: no such file or directory": unknow`n

where do i need to set this "--once" command in dockerized agent?

Answer (score 1):

Is for the agent's `run`, not the `docker run`. from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-interactively):

> For agents configured to run interactively, you can choose to have the
> agent accept only one job. To run in this configuration:
>
> `./run.sh --once`
>
> Agents in this mode will accept only one job and then spin down
> gracefully (useful for running in [Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops) on a service like Azure
> Container Instances).

So, you need to add it in the bash script you configure the docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        jq \
        git \
        iputils-ping \
        libcurl4 \
        libicu60 \
        libunwind8 \
        netcat

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh --once
```

Comment: n docker agent, i don't have run.sh , the docker starts with start.sh

Comment: That would pass `--once` to the `chmod` command, which is not what's wanted.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk did you try it ?
you passed parameter to chmod command ....

Comment: @user63898 No, but I think the second answer is correct, it shouldn't ve in the dockerfile, but in the `start.sh`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to pass it in from the outside; you have to go into the container and edit the `start.sh` file to add the `--once` argument to the appropriate line.

```
  exec ./externals/node/bin/node ./bin/AgentService.js interactive --once & wait $!
  cleanup
```

Side note: depending on your requirements, you might also take the opportunity to remove the undocumented web-server from `start.sh`.

Comment: Thank , but i dont understand this is not what written in the documents 
why i need to remove the web server ? also why i need to add the & wait $!?

Comment: Web server — that's up to you. If you need it, keep it; if you don't want it, remove it. It's entirely undocumented and doesn't appear to serve any useful purpose. Certainly the agent works fine without it.

Comment: The `& wait $!` is so the `cleanup` function can be run after the agent exits. If I remember correctly, this de-registers the agent from the pool. Probably it could be omitted if the `exec` is also removed.

Comment: wander why it is not documented

Comment: My guess is that the webserver is a dummy health-check endpoint; always returns a 3xx redirect response, without regard to agent health. It could also for some "must have a web interface" requirement checkbox; it redirects to the admin interface on Azure, rather than just giving "200 OK".